# Rails: Auto-Detecting Database Adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

The new version of the ar-extensions gem requires that you load the appropriate adapter yourself. On my development side I use mysql, however Heroku uses PostgreSQL.

For example, on my development side I need to do this:

```
require 'ar-extensions/adapters/mysql'
require 'ar-extensions/import/mysql'
```

How can I audo-detect which adapter to use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]['adapter']` will give you the name of the adapter in use.

The following code should do what you're after:

```
db_adapter = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]['adapter']
require "ar-extensions/adapters/#{db_adapter}"
require "ar-extensions/import/#{db_adapter}"
```